# C - warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

I have no clue why I am getting this warning when my variable and return value match. I have pasted below the variable, assignment of that variable to a function and the function itself (return value and all)

```
char * menuMsg;          /* used to print menu options */

menuMsg = printMenu();

char * printMenu()
{   
    static char message[250] = "Select an option from below:\n";
    strcat(message, "(1) List all files on server\n");
    strcat(message, "(2) Retrieve file from server\n");
    strcat(message, "(3) Retrieve all files from server\n");
    strcat(message, "Enter your selection: ");
    return message;
}
```

Any clues as to why i would be receiving this error? To me they all line up it terms of type declarations.

Comment: Do you have declaration for `printMenu` before the definition?

Comment: @wolfPack88 no I totally forgot. I have it included now and it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you're calling the function before it's declared. Undeclared functions are assumed to return `int`, which explains the error.

Move the `printMenu()` definition to before the function that's doing the call, or add a prototype:

```
char * printMenu(void);
```

And make sure you add `void`, `()` is wrong for a function accepting no parameters.

Also, your code is broken since each time you call `printMenu()` it will call `strcat()` four times, causing the menu text to grow and grow and eventually cause a buffer overrun.

Answer (score 4):

Please include these lines at the top of your code:

```
#include <string.h>
char * printMenu();
```

In the future, please include a fully compilable test case.